# Python `+=` operator and single line for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, operator-keyword

`weights` is a numpy array of a certain number of values, which is being multiplied by x^i. ***Without summing the elements of `weights`***, how do I rewrite this function in a one line for loop?

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
weights = np.zeros(order + 1)

def estimate(weights, x):
    est = 0
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        est += weights[i] * x ** i
    return est

estimate(weights, x)
```

I would like to rewrite this function in one line, such that:

```
est = [(est + (weights[i] * x ** i)) for i in range(len(weights))]
```

But this is not giving me the right output. What I don't understand is, why these two are not equivalent. How do you handle `+=` in a one line for loop? Is there maybe a different keyword that I could use that is eluding me right now?

---

EDIT: 
This is in fact the right answer:
`est = sum([(weights[i] * (x ** i)) for i in range(order + 1)])`
I had another bug in my code which prevented me from getting the correct result unrelated to this statement.
I apologize for all the trouble.

Comment: `sum([(weight * x ** i) for i, weight in enumerate(weights)])` isnt that what you want?

Comment: This doesn't exactly do what I want, I don't want to sum the entire list. Weights is an array.

Comment: @AhmadMoussa alpert's one-liner and your `estimate` function are equivalent (well... except for the return), so how does it not do what you want?

Comment: sum() sums up the individual values that are in the array weights and returns a singular number. I would like est to be returned as an array. And could someone tell me the reason for all the downvotes? So that I can fix it?

Comment: (Repeating off deceze a while earlier...) are you looking for `= [ ... ]` instead of `+= [ ... ]`? N.B. this doesn't seem to be what your function does.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe it is a bit more clearer now. Sorry for all the trouble...

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the additional context, but it isn't enough of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `order` is undefined and even if it is (I tried `order = 2` at the top), then I get a TypeError since `[0, 1, 2, 3] ** 0` is not valid python. Please ensure that the snippet posted reproduces your problem. (Random guess, perhaps you meant `x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])`?)

Comment: Hello again, sorry for all the inconvenience. The suggested statement was indeed the correct answer to my problem. But I had another bug in code that prevented this, and I assumed that this was the problem. Apologies again for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following one-liner does what you want:

```
est = sum([(weight * x ** i) for i, weight in enumerate(weights)])
```

Answer (score 1):

it is simply the sum of the elements of that comprehension list :

```
est = sum([(weight * x ** i) for i, weight in enumerate(weights)])
```